# Term commonly used for the type defined within a type trait

Tags: c++, type-traits

Let's define a type trait (we don't bother here about the actual definition of `type`):

```
template<typename T> struct sometrait  { using type = T; };
```

**Question:** is there a term commonly used for the `type` member of the struct that defines the trait ?

I guess that "type trait" should be used for the trait itself, so I'm not sure how to name `type` other than "the type defined within the type trait", which is a little bit tedious.

To clarify, I mean that a type trait often defines a conventional `type` member and I was wondering whether a conventional term specifically exist for it among the other member types of the trait.

Comment: It's called a *member typedef*.

Comment: There's usually no need to be more specific than "the trait's type" or "the type", since most people understand that it doesn't refer to the trait itself.

Comment: @edrezen If you have multiple *member typedef* then you call them just that. For example say you have one named `type` another named `anothertype`. Then you would call them like *member typedef `type`* and *member typedef `anothertype`* **It's not actually any different from how you would call multiple data members.** You would call data member `a`, data member `b` etc. Similarly you would here use member typedef `type` then member typedef `type2` etc.

Comment: When I picked up meta-programming, the term I saw thrown around for traits was "meta-functions", split into type and value meta-functions. As you may guess, the authors referred to the meta-function's "result type" and "result value". I still see this jargon thrown around from time to time, though we don't meta-program the same way any more nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

> is there a term commonly used for the type member

In the standard, the term formally used for `type` is ***member typedef***.

> here I mean that a type trait often defines a conventional type member and I was wondering whether a conventional term specifically exist for it among the other member types of the trait.

If you have multiple *member typedef* then you call them just that. For example say you have one named `type` another named `anothertype`. Then you would call them like *member typedef `type`* and *member typedef `anothertype`*

```
template<typename T> struct sometrait  
{ 
    using type = T;        //member typedef type
    using type2 = const T; //member typedef type2
};
```

---

This is not any different from how we'd call multiple data members. Say we have 2 data members named `a` and `b`. Then we refer to them as data member `a` and data member `b`. Similarly, in the case of member typedef we would refer to them as member typedef `a` and member typedef `b`.